# How to replace HTML with BASH

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I want to run a bash script on my server, and display the output on a web page. The script is started trough php, and is working. -but i wold like to colorize specific keywords. How is that best done?

**Possible solution:**

I can find the start of the keyword(warning) with `string.search("warning");` (I do not know how to find the end). -and pick out the keyword with `string.substring(from, to)`. Then use `string.fontcolor("red")` to colorize it, and `document.write(colorstring);` to display it.

**Edit:**

**I do not think my problem was clearly formulated, so I try again:**

php runs bash script, that returns text e.g.

```
"This is some text that bash returns"
```

How do I best transform that text into

```
"This is <span class='keyword'>some</span> text that bash returns"
```

so I can apply a colored style to the keyword("some")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is wrap, and then style, specific strings within a given string:

```
var str = "This is some text that bash returns",
    styledString = str.replace(/some/gi,'<span class="keyword">some</span>');
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/eVaGN/).

Comment: Yes - I see that would work. It is simple, and maybe the best solution. There is one thing, I do not like - you use one language(javascript), to insert code into another language(HTML). Javascript has it's own string methods(e.g. `string.fontcolor(color)`). I know I myself wrote <span>...!

Comment: Yeah, I sort of agree with your problem in the first comment, except that to use a 'pure-JavaScript' means of inserting an element at the right point, appending a `textNode` to it and then removing the original text from the string/HTML would be way more work than the end-result really deserves. Sometimes it's okay to simplify things and treat HTML as a string. Other times, of course, it's not. It is, of course, up to you whether you use this answer, though. =)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use `<span>` and CSS classes, not inline styles. Separation of style and data is important for a maintainable site.

```
<span class='keyword'>warning</span>
```

CSS:

```
.keyword {
   font-color:#ff0000;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you do not answer my question at all. Please see my updated explanation.